# How to update a label.text for each listview item selected using looping

Tags: c#, listview

So I have an idea on how solved my question but i need shorter codes

I have listview with imagelist on it.

everytime listview item selected index change 
label1.text  will also change or updates

here's my code

```
if (listView1.Items[0].Selected == true)
{
    label1.Text = "Number1";
}
if (listView1.Items[1].Selected == true)
{
    label1.Text = "Number2";
}
```

I try to ask if there's a way that utilize the looping to make the code short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `ListView`'s `ItemSelectionChanged` event then you can simply have:

```
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
{
   label1.Text = e.Item.Text;
}
```

But you will require more complicated code if the `ListView`'s `MultiSelect` property is set to `true`.

e.g.

```
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
{
   if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) 
   {
      label1.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
   }
}
```

You can use the `ListViewItem`'s `Index` property if you need its position.

Answer (score 0):

To show the selected item, you can try this

```
foreach (ListViewItem selectedItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    label1.Text = selectedItem.Text;
    break; // remove it if you have multiple selection but you need thread as well with Thread.Sleep.
}
//OR
label1.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```

For custom text

```
var count = 1;
foreach (ListViewItem selectedItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    label1.Text = "Number" + count++;
    break; // remove it if you have multiple selection but you need thread as well with Thread.Sleep.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options, `for` and `foreach`. `Foreach` is possibly more readable, but you don't get an index to work with, while `for` is less readable but has an index.

```
int i = 1;
foreach (var item in listView1.Items) {
    if (item.Selected == true) {
        label1.Text = "Number" + i;
    }
    i++;
}

//OR DO THIS

for (int i = 1; i <= listView1.Items.Length; i++) {
    if (item.Selected == true) {
        label1.Text = "Number" + i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a hidden column on the listview and that would be your label text then you could do the following

You would put that in a foreach loop such as;

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in ListView1)
{
   label1.Text = item.HiddenField;
}
```